# Call a batch file different times

Tags: batch-file

I'm calling a batch file from another one as follows

**caller.bat:**

```
CALL called.bat %param%=someValue1
CALL called.bat %param%=someValue2
CALL called.bat %param%=someValue3
```

I'm passing a parameter that's used in `called.bat`, the idea is to run the `called.bat` different times with a different parameter each time.
when the `caller.bat` runs, only the first call is executed!

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your `called.bat` completing successfully the first time?  If it is still waiting for something to occur, it will not pass control back to `caller.bat` and won't proceed to the 2nd call.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
start /b "" called.bat %param%=someValue1
```

Comment: What's the meaning of /b ""

Comment: `/b` stops the call from opening in a new window.

Comment: My solution is executed one time (first call) but called.bat did its work, the solution of Endoro executes all the calls but did not what I'm expecting from called.bat

Comment: this might be. But, nobody knows what you expect